# How do I run selenium test one after the other on multiple browser

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Not sure where am going wrong, i am trying to run same set of test one after the other on multiple browser.

> TestNG.xml

```
<suite  name="Selenium Tests"   parallel="false" thread-count="5">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ww5.listener.Listener" />
</listeners>
<test name="Chrome" preserve-order="true">
   <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
   <classes>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.version.version" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LoginTest" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LogoutTest" ></class>
   </classes>
</test>

<test name="Firefox" preserve-order="true">
   <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.version.version" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LoginTest" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LogoutTest" ></class>
     </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

When i run this, all the test are excuted on chrome, how do i make it excute on firefox after it finish excuting on chrome.

> OpenBrowser.java

```
@Parameters ({"browser"})
        @BeforeClass
        public void launchBrowser(String browser) throws Exception {
            //initLogs(this.getClass());
            initConfigurations();
            if (driver == null) {
            DesiredCapabilities cap = null;
            if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
            {
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
                //cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
                }
            if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internet explorer"))
            {
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                cap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
                cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
                }
            if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
            {
                cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
                cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
                }
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
            }
        }
```

Comment: need to know how to run hub/node

Comment: @Nguyen Vu Hoang Hub and Node are running fine

Comment: Update the code to include the driver definition, where have you implemented the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<suite  name="Selenium Tests"   parallel="false" thread-count="5">`
with

`<suite name="Selenium Tests" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">`

All other things seems to be fine. Refer [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/12/02/testng-executing-parallel-tests/) for more info.

**Edit:**

I understood your problem incorrectly. The issue that you are not able to run test sequentially is due to `if (driver == null)`. That mean your test will run well first time as driver is null, but after that due to your driver definition it may not be `null` and hence will not create another capability. So, if you remove it, the tests should run fine.

Comment: this will make the test run parallely, i want the test to run serially

Comment: @ayaslem see the edit, if issue still exists you may need to add driver definition to your post as well.